# Map Avro files on Java class with different field names

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-avro

I've got a problem with simple spark task, which reads Avro file and then save it as Hive parquet table.

I've got 2 types of file, in general they are the same, but the key struct is a little different - field names.

Type 1

```
root
|-- pk: strucnt (nullable = true)
    |-- term_id: string (nullale = true)
```

Type 2

```
root
|-- pk: strucnt (nullable = true)
    |-- id: string (nullale = true)
```

I'm reading Avro using spark-avro. And then map this DF to bean like this

```
Dataset<SomeClass> df = avroDF.as(Encoders.bean(SomeClass.class));
```

SomeClass is a simple one-field class with getter and setter.

```
public class SomeClass{
    private String term_id;
    ...
}
```

So if I'm reading Avro type 1 - it's OK. But if I'm reading Avro type 2 - the error occures. And vice versa if I'm changing the field name to `private String id;`

Is there any universal solution for my problem? I found @AvroName, but it doesn't allow to set several names.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution is

```
StructType avroExtendedSchema = avroDF.schema().add("id",DataTypes.StringType);
avroDF.map(row->RowFactory(row.getStruct(0),row.getStruct(0).getString(0)), 
       RowEncoder.apply(avroExtendedSchema)).toDF();
```

So the second field of DF will be named "id" and contain the string key. First "pk" struct can be dropped in the future.

```
avroDF.drop("pk");
```

PS
I found the third type of schema:

```
root
|-- pk: strucnt (nullable = true)
    |-- id: int(nullale = true)
```

So  the final code is like:

```
DataType keyType = avroDF.select("pk.*").schema().fields[0].dataType();
StructType avroExtendedSchema = avroDF.schema().add("id",keyType);
avroDF.map(row->RowFactory(row.getStruct(0),row.getStruct(0).get(0)), 
       RowEncoder.apply(avroExtendedSchema)).drop("pk").toDF();
```

This code suites for any primitive\String key.

Answer (score 1):

Only one way is to change dataset fieldname to the name which is in schema.
Use this example to do it:

```
val newName = Seq("id", "x1", "x2", "x3")
Dataset<SomeClass> df = avroDF.toDF(newNames: _*).as(Encoders.bean(SomeClass.class));
```

You can't cast dataframe to a BeanClass which has different field names.